# How to connect the sim card on a DELL laptop. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking

I want to connect to the mobile network using the sim card slot on my new Dell Precision. I have never done this.

I have checked that the WWAN card is there:

```
$ lspci
...
02:00.0 Wireless controller [0d40]: Intel Corporation XMM7360 LTE Advanced Modem (rev 01)
```

But there is no option to configure it in Settings>Network (only sections for "Wired" and "VPN" appear).

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Other information**

```
$ rfkill list
...
2: dell-wwan: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$ nmcli 
wlo1: connected to HOME_WIFI_NAME
        "Intel Wi-Fi"
        wifi (iwlwifi), 4C:79:6E:AA:86:3D, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.1.131/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 169.254.0.0/16
        route4 192.168.1.0/24
        inet6 fe80::9f37:8cbc:7d9b:dc5d/64
        route6 fe80::/64

p2p-dev-wlo1: disconnected
        "p2p-dev-wlo1"
        wifi-p2p, hw

eno2: unavailable
        "Intel Ethernet"
        ethernet (e1000e), 38:14:28:1D:B5:5B, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 212.230.135.2 212.230.135.1
        domains: Home
        interface: wlo1
```

Answer (score 1):

Native support wasn't added yet but it's being worked on.

Meanwhile try the following drivers/software:

```
mkdir ~/tmp/
cd ~/tmp/
sudo apt install build-essential python3-pyroute2 python3-configargparse git
git clone https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci.git
cd xmm7360-pci
make && make load
cp xmm7360.ini.sample xmm7360.ini  # edit at least the apn in the configuration file
sudo python3 rpc/open_xdatachannel.py
sudo ip link set wwan0 up
```

Source: https://github.com/xmm7360/xmm7360-pci

Comment: @user68186 It's not needed but it probably works with this, as well as other similar front-ends also mentioned in the linked answer. Thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: I executed everything sequentially ignoring the following errors: After ```make && make load``` I got the error  ```rmmod: ERROR: Module xmm7360 is not currently loaded; make: [Makefile:18: load] Error 1 (ignored)
``` . I edited the APN in the xmn7360.ini. After ```sudo python3 rpc/open_xdatachannel.py```  there were a bunch of numbers, and in the last line ```ERROR:root:Attach failed again, giving up```. It didn't work. Any follow-up advice?

Comment: Have you rebooted? (And you may need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI)

Comment: After rebooting and checking that Secure Boot is disabled, it is still not working. Btw, I'm checking if the connection is active with ```nmcli connection show```. Those errors looked like something went wrong in the installation of the drivers... Other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, it certainly looks like something went wrong and without the module it can't possibly work. I suggest you contact the developers at github.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same scenario. You need to change a setting in the DELL UEFI/BIOS menu under the "wireless menu" from PCIe to USB(recommended for non-Windows systems). Thereafter, your Linux computer will be able to automatically see the built-in modem.

Comment: Hello. What does a built in modem have to do with this?

Comment: The sim uses a built-in modem, and the name of the modem is Intel Corporation XMM7360 LTE Advanced Modem. @David